# Matlab axes scaling

Tags: matlab, plot, scale, axes

how exactly do you get fixed scaling of axes in Matlab plot when plotting inside a loop? My aim is to see how data is evolving inside the loop. I tried using `axis manual` and `axis(...)` with no luck. Any suggestions?

I know `hold on` does the trick, but I don't want to see the old data.

Comment: You might also want to read about the undocumented feature `LimInclude`: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-liminclude-properties/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see your new plotted data replace the old plotted data, but maintain the same axes limits, you can update the x and y values of the plotted data using the [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/set.html) command within your loop. Here's a simple example:

```
hAxes = axes;                     %# Create a set of axes
hData = plot(hAxes,nan,nan,'*');  %# Initialize a plot object (NaN values will
                                  %#   keep it from being displayed for now)
axis(hAxes,[0 2 0 4]);            %# Fix your axes limits, with x going from 0
                                  %#   to 2 and y going from 0 to 4
for iLoop = 1:200                 %# Loop 100 times
  set(hData,'XData',2*rand,...    %# Set the XData and YData of your plot object
            'YData',4*rand);      %#   to random values in the axes range
  drawnow                         %# Force the graphics to update
end
```

When you run the above, you will see an asterisk jump around in the axes for a couple of seconds, but the axes limits will stay fixed. You don't have to use the [HOLD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) command because you are just updating an existing plot object, not adding a new one. Even if the new data extends beyond the axes limits, the limits will not change.

Comment: +1 I also have a couple of suggestions: 1) to avoid flickering, you should enable double buffering `set(gcf,'DoubleBuffer','on')`. 2) if you want to increase the speed of drawing and get a smoother animation, set the `EraseMode` property to something other than 'normal' (I would use `xor` in this case). Of course you'll have to use low-level functions like line,patch,text,etc.. Check out this guide for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1200/1204.html#Section%2023

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the axes limits; ideally you do that before starting the loop.

This won't work

```
x=1:10;y=ones(size(x)); %# create some data
figure,hold on,ah=gca; %# make figure, set hold state to on
for i=1:5,
   %# use plot with axis handle 
   %# so that it always plots into the right figure
   plot(ah,x+i,y*i); 
end
```

This will work

```
x=1:10;y=ones(size(x)); %# create some data
figure,hold on,ah=gca; %# make figure, set hold state to on
xlim([0,10]),ylim([0,6]) %# set the limits before you start plotting
for i=1:5,
   %# use plot with axis handle 
   %# so that it always plots into the right figure
   plot(ah,x+i,y*i); 
end
```